# If $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ converge uniformly on $A \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ then $(f_n + g_n)$ converges uniformly, but not necessarily $(f_ng_n)$. Why?

Tags: real-analysis

It seems I can prove that if $(f_n) \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $A$ and $(g_n)\rightarrow g$ uniformly on $A$ then for arbitrary but fixed $x \in A$, $f_n(x) + g_n(x)\rightarrow f(x) + g(x) = (f+g)(x)$ via the algebraic limit theorem for sequences, as $f_n(x)$ and $g_n(x)$ are just sequences of numbers.

It seems I should be able to do the same with products, but I am aware there are counterexamples. Therefore there is an issue with invoking the algebraic limit theorem here, except I cannot see what it is.

There is clearly something I am missing - not sure exactly what.

Comment: Hard to respond to this question with anything resembling a full "answer," but think about how one would expect the argument to go, presumably making use of an equality like $f_n(x)g_n(x) - f(x)g(x) = f_n(x) (g_n(x) - g(x)) + (f_n(x) - f(x)) g(x)$. Having "uniform control" over the size of the $g_n(x) - g(x)$ and $f_n(x) - f_n(x)$ pieces of this expression does not translate in any obvious way to "control" over the full expression because of the lack of simultaneous "control" over the sizes of $f_n(x)$ and $g(x)$. See if this isn't where your counterexamples can be seen as "coming from"

Comment: What is $A$? If $A=\Bbb R$, then take $f_n=g_n=x^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of the algebraic limit theorem proves merely the pointwise convergence of $f_n(x)+g_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)+g(x)$ not uniform convergence. The same algebraic limit theorem asserts the pointwise convergence of $f_n(x)g_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)g(x)$. But neither case has anything to do with uniform convergence.

Comment: I think I see your point. To make sure: the algebraic limit theorem concerns some particular sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, so really ALT shows for whichever particular $(f_n(x))$ and $(g_n(x))$, such and such linear combination converges. But the definition of uniform convergence is fundamentally different: it says that given an $\epsilon$, I can find an $N$ that works for a (in all likelihood uncountable) collection of sequences. The definition is fundamentally different than ordinary convergence, so I can't invoke ALT to show uniform convergence. Even if $x$ varies over $A$. Is this right?

Comment: That's right. You fixed $x \in A$ and then you applied ALT, that's pointwise (ordinary) convergence. That's finding $N(\epsilon,x)$ i.e. $N$ depends on both $\epsilon$ and the point of consideration $x$. In uniform convergence, you need to find $N(\epsilon)$ that works for all $x \in A$ i.e. $N$ is a function of $\epsilon$ only, not $x$.